# CSS3 Slideshow Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey there I took inspiration from this [article](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/05/slideshow-with-jmpress-js) for my slideshow. I worked with the source code from the website to make it my own and when I copy/pasted the html & css over to my project html & css files it doesn't seem to load.

I went over my code again and again but still haven't managed to solve the problem. It's working perfectly in the seperate html file but just not in my project file.

I would appreciate any help to solve this issue I'm having.

Screenshots:

Working in seperate file:

http://gyazo.com/712175106aeeb7b636b19937cf2c09c8

Project File where it doesn't appear to load or display:

http://gyazo.com/cc41a9cd0636c71dac6bb71edc4eff1a

**Code for my project verision:**

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

The Dark Lanes

```
<!-- Page Styling --> 
<link href="css/Index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 

<!-- Navigation --> 
<link href="css/nav.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<!-- Slideshow -->
<link href="css/Slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!-- jmpress plugin -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/jmpress.min.js"></script>

<!-- jmslideshow plugin : extends the jmpress plugin -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/jmslideshow.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/autoplay.js"></script>



<!-- JQuery Plugin --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/modernizr.js"></script>

<!-- Twitter Plugin --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/Twitter.js"></script>

<!-- Including the Lobster font from Google's Font Directory -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:700,300,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!-- Enabling HTML5 support for Internet Explorer -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

```
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <!--<header>
        <img src="Images/DarkLanes-Logo.png" alt="header"/>
    </header> --> 

    <!-- Navigation --> 

    <ul id="menu">

        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="gigs.html">Gigs</a></li>
        <li><a href="music.html">Music</a></li>
            <li> 
                <a href="#">Biography</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="band profile.html">Band Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="member profiles.html">Member Profiles</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </li>
            `<li>

                <a href="#">Media</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="images.html">Images</a></li>
                        <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
                    </ul>

            </li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- End of Nav --> 

    <div class="left">
        <h3><a href="index.html">The Dark Lanes</a></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="right"></div>



    <!-- Start of Slideshow -->


    <section id="jms-slideshow" class="jms-slideshow">

        <div class="step" data-color="color-2">
            <div class="jms-content">
                <h3>Just when I thought...</h3>
                <p>From fairest creatures we desire increase, that thereby beauty's rose might never die</p>
                    <a class="jms-link" href="#">Read more</a>
            </div>
                <img src="images/The Dark Lanes.jpg" alt="image1 />
        </div>

        <div class="step" data-color="color-3" data-y="900" data-rotate-x="80">
            <div class="jms-content">
                <h3>Holy cannoli!</h3>
                <p>But as the riper should by time decease, his tender heir might bear his memory</p>
                    <a class="jms-link" href="#">Read more</a>
            </div>
                <img src="images/Stage.jpg" alt="image2" />
        </div>

        <div class="step" data-color="color-4" data-x="-100" data-z="1500" data-rotate="170">
            <div class="jms-content">
                    <h3>The Rocker</h3>
                <p>But as the riper should by time decease, his tender heir might bear his memory</p>
                    <a class="jms-link" href="videos.html">View Video!</a>
            </div>
                <img src="images/Darlanes.jpg" alt="image3" />
        </div>

        <div class="step" data-color="color-5" data-x="3000">
            <div class="jms-content">
                    <h3>Supercool!</h3>
                <p>Making a famine where abundance lies, thyself thy foe, to thy sweet self too cruel</p>
                    <a class="jms-link" href="#">Read more</a>
            </div>
                <img src="images/The Dark Lanes2.jpg" alt="image4" />
        </div>

        <div class="step" data-color="color-1" data-x="4500" data-z="1000" data-rotate-y="45">
            <div class="jms-content">
                    <h3>Did you know that...</h3>
                <p>Thou that art now the world's fresh ornament and only herald to the gaudy spring</p>
                    <a class="jms-link" href="#">Read more</a>
            </div>
                <img src="images/The Dark Lanes3.jpg" alt="image5" />
        </div>
    </section> 

    <div id="content">


    <!-- Social Media Plugins --> 
    <div id="facebook">

        <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FTDLmusic%2Fposts%2F634412299948671&amp;width=300&amp;height=258&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;show_faces=true&amp;header=false&amp;stream=false&amp;show_border=false&amp;appId=1407117389534500" 
        scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:300px; height:245px; background-color:#373737;">
        </iframe>

    </div>

    <div class="twitter-timeline">

        <a class="twitter-timeline"  href="https://twitter.com/TheDarkLanes"  data-widget-id="422456331014901760">Tweets by @TheDarkLanes</a>

    </div>

     <!-- End of Social Media Plugins --> 

        <div class="video">

        <iframe width="600" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/hEkpJMxci2Y" frameborder="0">
        </iframe>

        </div>

        <!--Social Media Logos --> 
    <div class="social-mediabg">

        <h3>The Dark Lanes</h3>

    </div>

    <div class="social-media">

        <ul>
            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/TDLmusic?fref=ts"><img src="Images/facebook.png" alt="facebook"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://twitter.com/TheDarkLanes"><img src="Images/twitter.png" alt="twitter"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/TheDarkLanes"><img src="Images/youtube.png" alt="youtube"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://soundcloud.com/thedarklanes"><img src="Images/soundcloud.png" alt="soundcloud"/></a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>

    </div>


    <div id="footer">

    <div class="SiteMap">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="gigs.html">Gigs</a></li>
            <li><a href="music.html">Music</a></li>
            <li><a href="band profile.html">Band Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="member profiles.html">Member Profiles</a></li>
            <li><a href="images.html">Images</a></li>
            <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    </div>

    <div id="copyright">

        <div class = "copyright">
            <h5>&copy; 2014 - The Dark Lanes. All Rights Reserved.</h5>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.jms-slideshow {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 650px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.jms-wrapper {
    width: 995px;
    height: 650px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    -webkit-background-clip: padding;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;     
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    outline: none;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 1s linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 1s linear;
    transition: background-color 1s linear;
}

.color-1 {
    background-color: #E3D8FF;
    background-color: rgba(227, 216, 268, 1);
}
.color-2 {
    background-color: #EBBBBC;
    background-color: rgba(235, 187, 188, 1);
}
.color-3 {
    background-color: #EED9C0;
    background-color: rgba(238, 217, 192, 1);
}
.color-4 {
    background-color: #DFEBB1;
    background-color: rgba(223, 235, 177, 1);
}
.color-5{
    background-color: #C1E6E5;
    background-color: rgba(193, 230, 229, 1);
}

.step { 
    width: 995px;
    height: 650px;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.jms-content{
    margin: 0px 0px 300px 20px;
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
}

.step:not(.active) {
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* internet explorer */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0)"; /*IE8*/
}

.step h3{
    color: grey;
    font-size: 52px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 60px 0 10px 0;
}
.step p {
    color: grey;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    font-size: 34px;
    font-weight: normal;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
}
a.jms-link{
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #969696; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #969696 0%, #727272 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#969696), color-stop(100%,#727272)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #969696 0%,#727272 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #969696 0%,#727272 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #969696 0%,#727272 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #969696 0%,#727272 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#969696', endColorstr='#727272',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    padding: 8px 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border: 1px solid #444;
    border-radius: 4px;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: 40px;
    clear: both;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 1s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 1s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 1s;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 1s;
}
.step:not(.active) a.jms-link{
    opacity: 0;
    margin-top: 80px;
}
.step img{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
.jms-dots{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 2000;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.jms-dots span{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #777;
    margin: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 
        1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1) inset, 
        1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
.jms-dots span.jms-dots-current:after{
    content: '';
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #f6f6f6 47%, #ededed 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(47%,#f6f6f6), color-stop(100%,#ededed)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ededed',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
.jms-arrows{
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.jms-arrows span{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -40px;
    height: 80px;
    width: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 2000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.jms-arrows span.jms-arrows-prev{
    background: #fff url(../images/arrow_left.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    left: -10px;
}
.jms-arrows span.jms-arrows-next{
    background: #fff url(../images/arrow_right.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    right: -10px;
}
/* Not supported style */
.jms-wrapper.not-supported{
    background-color: #E3D8FF;
    background-color: rgba(227, 216, 268, 1);
}
.jms-wrapper.not-supported:after{
    content: 'The slideshow functionality is not supported on your device.';
    padding: 0px 0px 30px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
.jms-wrapper.not-supported .step{
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=99); /* internet explorer */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=99)"; /*IE8*/
    margin: 20px auto;
}
.jms-wrapper.not-supported .step:first-of-type{
    display: block;
}
.jms-wrapper.not-supported .step:not(.active) a.jms-link{
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

Comment: the jmpress jQuery plugin before jQuery? try loading the other way around

Answer (score 1):

You should be loading the jQuery before the jmpress plugin :)

jmpress is a jQuery plugin, and therefore wont work if you haven't loaded it before!

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    <title>RosePam Solutions Ltd</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">      

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:700,300,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_ie.css" />
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- load jQuery and the plugin -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bjqs-1.3.min.js"></script>

   <!-- jmpress plugin -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jmpress.min.js"></script>

    <!-- jmslideshow plugin : extends the jmpress plugin -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jmslideshow.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.48780.js"></script>

    <noscript>
        <style>
        .step {
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;
        }
        .step:not(.active) {
            opacity: 1;
            filter: alpha(opacity=99);
            -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=99)";
        }
        .step:not(.active) a.jms-link{
            opacity: 1;
            margin-top: 40px;
        }
        </style>
    </noscript>
</head>

<body class="body">
    <div class="content">
        <section id="jms-slideshow" class="jms-slideshow">
            <div class="step" data-color="color-2">
                <img src="images/The Dark Lanes.jpg" alt="image1 />
                <div class="jms-content">
                    <h3><span>Just when I thought...</span></h3>
                    <p><span>From fairest creatures we desire increase, that thereby beauty's rose might never die</span></p>
                    <a class="jms-link" href="#">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="step" data-color="color-3" data-y="900" data-rotate-x="80">
                <img src="images/Stage.jpg" alt="image2" />
                <div class="jms-content">
                    <h3><span>Holy cannoli!</span></h3>
                    <p><span>But as the riper should by time decease, his tender heir might bear his memory</span></p>
                    <a class="jms-link" href="#">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="step" data-color="color-4" data-x="-100" data-z="1500" data-rotate="170">
                <img src="images/Darlanes.jpg" alt="image3" />
                <div class="jms-content">
                    <h3><span>Supercool!<span></h3>
                    <p><span>Making a famine where abundance lies, thyself thy foe, to thy sweet self too cruel</span></p>
                    <a class="jms-link" href="#">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="step" data-color="color-5" data-x="3000">
                <img src="images/The Dark Lanes3.jpg" alt="image5" />
                <div class="jms-content">
                    <h3><span>Did you know that...</span></h3>
                    <p><span>Thou that art now the world's fresh ornament and only herald to the gaudy spring</span></p>
                    <a class="jms-link" href="#">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {

                var jmpressOpts = {
                animation       : { transitionDuration : '0.8s' }

            };

            $( '#jms-slideshow' ).jmslideshow( $.extend( true, { jmpressOpts : jmpressOpts }, {
                autoplay    : true,
                bgColorSpeed: '0.8s',
                arrows      : false
                }));

            });
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is how your html file should look like. Make sure also you load all the plugins required in terms of javascript.